# __FUNCDNAME__ returns incorrect decorated function name

Tags: c++, macros, clr, dllexport, name-decoration

Function signature is:

```
void __stdcall Test(char *,int)
```

[__FUNCDNAME__](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019) macro used within function returns decorated function name:

- real function name inside image: **?Test@@YGXPADH@Z**
- __FUNCDNAME__ returns: **?Test@@YGXPADH@Z**

When [/clr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation?view=vs-2017) option is on (Project > Properties > General > Common Language Runtime Support > /clr) __FUNCDNAME__ macro doesn't return real decorated function name:

- real function name inside image: **?Test@@YGXPADH@Z**
- __FUNCDNAME__ returns: **?Test@@**$$F**YGXPADH@Z**  __FUNCDNAME__ macro doesn't return real decorated function name.

This makes it impossible to use the **#pragma comment** directive to export function from DLL **directly** from the code **without** name decoration:

```
// .h
/*__declspec(dllexport)*/ void __stdcall Test(char *p1, int p2);

// .cpp
void __stdcall Test(char *p1, int p2)
{
    #pragma message("Exporting function " __FUNCTION__ " [" __FUNCDNAME__ "]")
    #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__)
}
```

Returns linker error LNK1242 '?Test@@$$FYGXPADH@Z' is an invalid export symbol name.

Comment: What happens if you declare the function inside extern "C" {} ?

Comment: extern "C" {} is usable only with default calling convention (__cdecl). When you need anything else (e.g. __stdcall) function name is decorated in form "_Test@BYTE_COUNT" even though extern "C" is used.

Comment: I see, then why don't you use a .def file.

Comment: The decorated symbol name is correct.  But it is not the one that can be exported, you need another one that takes care of switching from unmanaged to managed mode.  Can't get that one from the macaroni, use `__declspec(dllexport)` instead.

Comment: @Michael: I preferred a solution (a little more elegant) that allows the function to be exported directly from the code without name decoration and without the need to explicitly name it.
It seems that using module definition file (.def) is the only workaround.

Comment: @Hans: I was unable to export function name without name decoration when using __declspec(dllexport).